# Ignoring all input characters until 'a' is entered - using scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying a basic code snippet on C. My intention is to ignore all characters until 'a' is entered by the user and then copy the next non-whitespace character to x.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x ;
    printf ("Input character - ") ;
    scanf  (" a %c", &x) ;
    printf ("x=%c is the input", x) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

I give input in the console as:

```
a <enter>
s <enter>
```

I get the output as: `x=s is the input`. This is correct.

But when I give input in the console as:

```
b <enter>
```

The execution finishes suddenly and I get the output as: `x= is the input`.

I don't understand this behavior. I was expecting the program to ignore 'b' and subsequent characters until 'a' is entered by the user. Did I interpret the scanf statement wrongly?

Comment: Use a loop that reads all characters one by one (with e.g. [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) or similar) to check for the `'a'` character input. Also remember to check for `EOF` (and remember that all the character input functions return an **`int`**, which is rather important for that `EOF` check).

Comment: `Did I interpret the scanf statement wrongly?` Is your interpretation of `scanf(" a")` a "block and read until character "a" is encountered on input"?

Comment: Your code waits for **exactly one** `a` character. There is no notion of "until" in there.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can you tell me why `a <enter> s <enter>` worked though? It looked like 'a' was ignored and then 's' was copied.

Comment: Meenie Leis, Try `if (scanf("%*[^a]a %c", &x) ==1) ...` to 1) scan and ignore all non-`a`, 2) scan an `a`, 3) ignore white-space 4) scan a `char`.  Personally I think [`getchar()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557514/ignoring-all-input-characters-until-a-is-entered-using-scanf-in-c#comment121160847_68557514) is the way for you to go.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. It will tell you the number of items that were successfully converted. If you enter `b` it will return 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Enter is whitespace.

Comment: @KamilCuk yea, that was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did I interpret the scanf statement wrongly?

Yes. Let's say `scanf` generally does:

- reads one character from input
- checks if it matches the format string
- if it matches, `scanf` continues to the next part of the string
- if it does not match, `scanf` calls `ungetc` and exits
- `scanf` returns number of arguments scanned or `EOF` in case of error or if there were no arguments scanned.

If you do `scanf(" a %c", &x);`, and type `b <enter>` then:

- `scanf` reads `b`
- `b` does not match `" "` (space)

  - `" "` space is magical, it matches *zero or more* whitespace characters
  - so `scanf` continues
  - `b` does not match `a`
- `scanf` calls `ungetc('b')`
- `scanf` returns with `EOF`

In such case `x` is never assigned and `x` is uninitialized and contains some garbage value. Most probably in the output `x=>here< is` there is some unprintable invisible character.

Answer (score 1):

By using `scanf("a%c",&x);` you are preformatting the input to be accepted if it would be like 'ab' , 'ac' , 'aa' and give 'b' , 'c' and 'a' as the `o/p` respectively, and will not accept anything alike those ones.
(Can also give `o/p`for inputs like 'aaa' , 'abc' as 'a' , 'b' respectively)

And for your task you can try this code below :- (Completely tested)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x ;
    do{
        scanf("%c",&x);
    }while(x != 'a');      //Read until x is not 'a'
    
    scanf("%c",&x);        //Read next character from standard input into x
    printf("%c",x);        //And then print x
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, however I don't want whitespaces to be accepted for x, so the second scanf has to be ----- `scanf(" %c, &x) ;`